# Linux - Create backups of multiple directories in bulk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, tar, archiving

I'm wondering if it is possible to create backups of multiple directories with one command in Linux. Specifically different websites hosted on a VPS.

Let's say for example I have four websites in the /var/www:

> /var/www/site01
>   /var/www/site02
>   /var/www/site03
>   /var/www/site04

I want to use tar to compress each of these directories. Is it possible to use a single command to compress every sub directory in /var/www to it's own separate archive?

> site01.tar, site02.tar, site03.tar, site04.tar

Comment: Try *rsync -a*.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "one command". One simple approach would be a loop that just runs tar for each directory.

Comment: What I don't want to do is type out each directory manually, the idea being that I can just use cron to automate backup of all sites, but I also want it to work if I add new sites without manually having to add another cron job. I was wondering if I could use PHP, add the contents of /var/www to an array, then a foreach loop running tar on each one?

Comment: Not even using gzip? Text (like HTML files) compresses wonderfully

Answer (score 5):

## How do I `tar` multiple directories?

Automate!

As mentioned by @Seth in the comments, a script if the way to go here if your goal is to reduce unnecessary typing.

```
#!/bin/bash
# backup_dirs_to_tars.sh - back up directories in $backupdir to 
# individual tars in $outputdir
# NB ignores .hidden (dotted) directories

backupdir=/var/www/
outputdir=/home/example/backups

cd $backupdir

for dir in */; do
        tar -cf "$outputdir/$(basename $dir).tar" "$dir"
done
```

Explanation:

- change to `$backupdir`
- `for dir in */` loops through *directories* in `$backupdir` (due to the trailing `/`)
- create `tar` archive of each directory (named after directory via `basename`) in the specified `$outputdir`

If you prefer, you can of course create `gzip`ped archives by changing the creation line to `tar -czf "$outputdir/$(basename $dir).tar.gz" "$dir"` instead.

## Wider Thinking About Backups (Additional Resources)

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your backup regimen, but it is worth being aware of [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) (uses `rsync` and increments) and [`rsnapshot`](http://rsnapshot.org/) (uses hard links to save space on files that don't change); both of which are simple to use and provide 'older versions' of files depending on how you use them.

It is also worth remembering the mantra: *'an untested backup is no backup'*. Make sure you can restore from a backup! Both `rdiff-backup` and `rsnapshot` provide a working set which can be browsed immediately, which is useful for verifying that a backup does indeed work.

Comment: Great solution. Worked for me. I added the ' --exclude "backups/*" ' parameter just before the "$dirs", to exclude that directory. Maybe that will help someone have a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar strategy to backup my Linux servers at work to a windows shared  folder. Basically I backup the contents in www, /etc/apache2 and the MySQL databases. I setup a cron job to do it automatically, it's been running on its own for years. Here is how I did it  https://ittutorials.net/linux/ubuntu/how-to-backup-ubuntu-to-a-windows-share/

Comment: Adding at least a brief version of the instructions would make this an answer. As it is, it's just a link, and they tend to disappear